# divide array element by array's sum vba

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, sum, division

I am creating an array Z and then i want to divide each element in the array by the array's sum, but for some reason i retrieve a #value error in the cells when im trying to run the function and i dont know why, since when i apply the exact same functions in the worksheet itself it works fine.

```
Option Base 1
Function getZ(Stockreturns, c1)
Dim nCols As Integer
nCols = Stockreturns.Columns.Count

Dim covmatrix() As Double
ReDim covmatrix(nCols, nCols)

For i = 1 To nCols
    For j = 1 To nCols
        covmatrix(i, j) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Covariance_S(Stockreturns.Columns(i), Stockreturns.Columns(j))
    Next j
Next i
   
Dim Ret(), PortU(), Z(), output() As Double
ReDim Ret(nCols, 1), PortU(nCols, 1)


For i = 1 To nCols
    Ret(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Stockreturns.Columns(i))
    PortU(i, 1) = Ret(i, 1) - c1
Next i

Z = Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(Application.WorksheetFunction.MInverse(covmatrix), PortU)

For i = 1 To nCols
    output(i) = Z(i) / Application.Sum(Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(Application.WorksheetFunction.MInverse(covmatrix), PortU))
Next i
getZ = output

End Function
```

Thats my code so far and it works just fine until the last for loop.

Comment: Have you stepped through? Should `Z` be 2d? Also you don't dimension `output` at all.

Comment: ```output(i)``` would create runtime error 9 because it's an empty array, so you can't access its nonexistent indices.

Comment: @BigBen I have Option Base 1 in the code forgot to post it

Comment: @SJR what do you mean? Im not that familiar with VBA, Z should represent a column vector

Comment: Sort out `output` first, that is definitely wrong. I can't work out Z in my head but even a single column is 2d in VBA sometimes.

Comment: Instead of calling this from a cell, call it from a subroutine and then step through with F8 to debug further. As already mentioned, `output` is not dimensioned, which is an obvious issue. There may be more.

Comment: Note: in `Dim Ret(), PortU(), Z(), output() As Double` only `output` is declared `Double`, the rest is variant.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie that's actually a good thing here otherwise there would be a lot more errors to clean up.